# Why use a heating block?

Tags: experimental-chemistry

Is a heating block necessary for heating small chemistry samples? I figure it helps a ton (not to mention it stabilizes too) in getting heat to the reaction but is there anything else it does?

Comment: Welcome to chemistry.se! If you have questions about how to beautify your posts, have a look at the [help]. Do you want to know more about this site, please take the [tour].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*You have already mostly answered the question yourself ;)*

A heating block, made from a material with a high thermal conductivity, helps to keep (**a lot of**) samples distributed over a larger area (several vials, Eppendorf tubes, etc.) at exactly the same temperature even if the primary heat source is punctual or just a layer of heating wires at the bottom of the instrument.